# Can one deduce a formula from a set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas with wrong values!?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Please have look at this propositional consequence problem (page 54, A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic):

$\Gamma = \{P(x,y,x), x<y ~\vee M(\omega,p), \neg P(x,y,z) ~\wedge (\neg x < y)\}$

I'm gonna investigate into the deduction of $\neg M(\omega,p)$ from set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas above.

1- AFAIK, all formulas of $\Gamma$ **must** be true. So please have a look at below deduction:

$P(x,y,x)$ is true. So $\neg P(x,y,x)$ is false and its logical intersection with every other formula is false, too. So, the third element of $\Gamma$, i.e. $\neg P(x,y,z) ~\wedge (\neg x < y)$ is false. How is it possible?

2- The other ambiguity is about the precedence of operators where both logical and algebraic operators will be used, together. As an instance, $(x < y)$ is something usual to compare $x$ and $y$, but what does $(\neg x < y)$ mean?

[image]

Comment: Of course, $(\lnot x < y)$ is (badly written) for $\lnot (x < y)$. We negate formulae (i.e. *statements*) and not variables (i.e. *names*) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have introduced a [typo](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA54); it is :

> $\Gamma = \{ P(x,y,x), x < y \lor M(w,p), \lnot P(x,y,x) \land (\lnot x < y) \}$.

We have to "map" the formulae to propositional formulae, replacing atoms with propositional variables:

> $\Gamma^* = \{ A, B \lor C, \lnot A \land \lnot B \}$

and $\lnot C$ for $\lnot M(w,p)$.

Thus, we have reduced the problem to check if $\Gamma^* \vDash \lnot C$.

So, your first comment is correct: the set $\Gamma^*$ (and obviously also $\Gamma$) is *inconsistent* : **no** truth assignment can makes all the formulas in it simultaneously true.

This means that there is no truth assignment that makes each formulas in $\Gamma^*$ true and makes $\lnot M(w,p)$ false.

Conclusion, $\lnot M(w,p)$ is (vacuously) a *propositional consequence* (see [**Def.2.4.1**](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52)) of $\Gamma$.

---

See [Principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) (or *Ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet*) :

> from contradiction, anything (follows).

Comment: Does `$\neg M(w,p)$ is (vacuously) a propositional consequence of \Gamma$` mean actually that `$\neg M(w,p)$ is NOT a propositional consequence of \Gamma$`? Because we can't deduce it from $\Gamma$